# Limit number of images to upload in wp.media function

Tags: media, uploads

I need to edit a plugin for my website. The plugin uses wp.media function and lets user upload images from the frontend.

A user should be able to upload multiple images. But, I need to set limit 
 on the number of images based on user role.

I tried searching a lot for wp.media function options but I could not find the solution.

I already tried using `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` filter. It works within posts & pages. But, it is not working with this plugin because it is using `wp.media` function.

How can I limit the number of images an user can upload using `wp.media()` function?